# making sure that every new position is different from previous two positions

Tags: ios, objective-c

Below is a method I wrote that takes a random number and makes sure that a sprite does repeat consecutively at the same position. I want to change it so that every new sprite takes a different position of the other two. I am not really getting it right. Please help.

```
- (float)randomlyChooseXValue    {
    CGSize s = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];

    int randX = arc4random() % 3;

    if (oldRandX != randX) {
        if (randX == 0) {
            xPos = xPos1*(s.width/480.0);
        } else if (randX == 1)    {
            xPos = xPos2*(s.width/480.0);
        } else {
            xPos = xPos3*(s.width/480.0);
        }
        oldRandX = randX;
    } else {
        [self randomlyChooseXValue];
    }
    return xPos;
}
```

Comment: try returning the randX var. that seems to be the location of your sprite

Comment: @Martol1ni: the code is working - it makes sure two consecutive positions don't repeat. But I want to change it so that one position can only repeat after the other two have been taken.

Comment: You realize that if you do that, since you have only three positions, the first two will be random, but the third must be the remaining position? After that they must continue to repeat in the same sequence.

Comment: @morningstar: yes, I've realized that, but that's what will work for me.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly you need to find 3 random values and the 3rd one should be different then the 1st 2. If this is true you need to store last 2 random values and compare them in the 1st `if` statement:

```
- (float)randomlyChooseXValue    {
    CGSize s = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];

    int randX = arc4random() % 3;

    if ((oldRandX1 != randX) && (oldRandX2 != randX)) { //check for 2 values
        if (randX == 0) {
            xPos = xPos1*(s.width/480.0);
        } else if (randX == 1)    {
            xPos = xPos2*(s.width/480.0);
        } else {
            xPos = xPos3*(s.width/480.0);
        }
        oldRandX2 = oldRandX1; //store 1st value to 2nd place
        oldRandX1 = randX; //store new value to 1st place
    } else {
        [self randomlyChooseXValue];
    }
    return xPos;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you explained that you are okay with the sequence repeating, then you only need to really make two random choices: the first position, and the direction.

```
// somewhere, initialize global oldRandX = -1, dir = -1

- (float)randomlyChooseXValue    {
    CGSize s = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];

    if (oldRandX < 0) {
        oldRandX = arc4random() % 3;
        dir = arc4random() % 2;
    } else if (dir) {
        oldRandX = (oldRandX + 1) % 3;
    } else {
        oldRandX = (oldRandX + 2) % 3;
    }

    if (randX == 0) {
        xPos = xPos1*(s.width/480.0);
    } else if (randX == 1)    {
        xPos = xPos2*(s.width/480.0);
    } else {
        xPos = xPos3*(s.width/480.0);
    }

    return xPos;
}
```

This can generate every possible sequence of the three positions:

- 0, 1, 2
- 0, 2, 1
- 1, 2, 0
- 1, 0, 2
- 2, 0, 1
- 2, 1, 0

and repeat them.

The other answer will achieve the same results, but like your original method, it might take several tries to get it. Your random function can keep choosing the wrong value an unbounded number of times; it becomes a worse problem when there's only one right number to pick.